# Too many Aristotles, too many Averroeses and too many semi-colons in Biblatex: how can I make \citeauthor behave more like \textcite?

Tags: biblatex

Biblatex provides both `\textcite` and `\citeauthor`, among other commands, for citing resources in the body of a document.

Unlike `\textcite`, however, `\citeauthor` does not behave as I'd expect. Possibly, it also does not behave as it used to, but I'm not sure about this.

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}

\verb|\Textcite| and \verb|\textcite| behave as expected:

\Textcite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} once took a bath.

\Textcite{averroes/bland,averroes/hannes} and \textcite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} opened the tin of soup together.

\verb|\Citeauthor| and \verb|\citeauthor| do not behave as expected\footnote{By me.}:

\Citeauthor{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} once took a bath.

\Citeauthor{averroes/bland,averroes/hannes} and \citeauthor{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} opened the tin of soup together.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would expect this to combine multiple references by the same author when `\citeauthor` is used, just as it does when `\textcite` is used. However, that does not happen:

[image: <code>\textcite</code> vs. <code>\citeauthor</code> (default style)]

If I use `authoryear-comp`, things look even worse:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}

\verb|\Textcite| and \verb|\textcite| behave as expected:

\Textcite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} once took a bath.

\Textcite{averroes/bland,averroes/hannes} and \textcite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} opened the tin of soup together.

\verb|\Citeauthor| and \verb|\citeauthor| do not behave as expected\footnote{By me.}:

\Citeauthor{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} once took a bath.

\Citeauthor{averroes/bland,averroes/hannes} and \citeauthor{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} opened the tin of soup together.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I would expect the names of multiple authors here to be separated by commas, but semi-colons are used. Now, that is all very well - and expected - in parenthetical citations, but it is not appropriate in the flow of text.

[image: <code>\textcite</code> vs. <code>\citeauthor</code> (<code>authoryear-comp</code>)]

Of course, in this particular case, the use of semi-colons is only problematic because the authors' names are unexpectedly repeated. However, I might want something like

```
\Citeauthor{aristotle:poetics,averroes/bland} ate the soup.
```

[image: semi-colon]

I could understand it if Biblatex used a comma where I'd expect an `and`, but a semi-colon is simply absurd.

Is this behaviour expected? I am inclined to regard it as a bug, but, for all I know, it is a cherished feature!

Either way, what is the best way to stop it? I'm wondering here about the most general solution, taking into account the fact that this problematic pattern probably infects more than just `\citeauthor`.

Comment: It definitely affects more than just `\citeauthor`, which is defined in (e.g.) `biblatex.def` in a very simple way, especially compared to the way `\textcite` is defined in `authoryear-comp.cbx`. `\citeauthor` is classified in `biblatex.def` as a 'generic citation command' and, basically, just `\printnames{labelname}` (compare `\citetitle`, `\citeyear`, etc.). I guess the reason being that if you just want 'Aristotle' to appear, you are just supposed to pick one representative entry to rely on. (If you are using `\citeauthor` to get into the index, however, this may not be desirable.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, I think the way we are supposed to cite multiple authors with `\textcite` is to use `\textcites`, which is defined as a 'multicite' command (and, interestingly, `\texcite` in `biblatex.def` is defined with `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand`, though it is not in `authoryear-comp.cbx`).

Comment: @jon I used to think that about the multicite commands, but I believe it is not true. For example, there would be no point in `sortcites` otherwise as setting it true or false would make no difference if you always use the multicite versions for 2+ authors,

Comment: Oh, I agree to a certain extent. But, at the very least, the definition of `\citeauthor` definitely does not truly cater to multiple citations of the same author, and its reliance on `\multicitedelim` in its definition is -- at best -- useful for citing a list of authors (e.g., `Here's a short list of people who get excited about the agent intellect: \citeauthor{averroes,aquinas}`). Given the fact that `numeric.cbx` defines `\textcite` in a tricky way and `\citeauthor` is defined in `biblatex.def` in a simplistic way suggests to me the difference between the two is very much by design.

Comment: @jon So maybe I should ask, how can I have a version of `\textcite` which doesn't print the year?!

Comment: I think the short answer is to adapt `\newbibmacro{textcite}` (call it `{textcitenoyear}`) so it only does the names and then essentially create a clone of the `\textcite` command. (Of course, there are often shorter ways to do things than the ways I come up with.)

Comment: Oh my, it seems I finally found out who was in the dinner! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem

Comment: @PauloCereda The problem is, they didn't put Kant in charge. Indeed, he doesn't even seem to be invited. If they had followed his advice about dinners, they wouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `sortcites` is enabled with a style that sorts by name first, we can actually be quite quick

```
\newbibmacro*{citeauthor}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
    {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
       {}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \usebibmacro{citeauthor}}
  {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

We just remember the last name, and don't print the current name if it coincides with the last.

Note how this definition uses `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` and not `\multicitedelim` since that might give a semicolon, depending on your style.

In the MWE there is additional code to make this run with styles that don't support `cite:init` and `cite:reinit`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}

\makeatletter
\providebibmacro*{cite:reinit}{%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\providebibmacro*{cite:init}{\usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}

\newbibmacro*{citeauthor}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
    {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
       {}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \usebibmacro{citeauthor}}
  {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|\Textcite| and \verb|\textcite| behave as expected:

\Textcite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} once took a bath.

\Parencite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} once took a bath.

\Textcite{averroes/bland,averroes/hannes} and \textcite{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} opened the tin of soup together.

\verb|\Citeauthor| and \verb|\citeauthor| do not behave as expected\footnote{By me.}:

\Citeauthor{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} once took a bath.

\Citeauthor{averroes/bland,averroes/hannes} and \citeauthor{aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics,aristotle:rhetoric} opened the tin of soup together.

\Citeauthor{averroes/bland,knuth:ct:a,averroes/hannes}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

For the fun of it, here is a solution based on `\textcite` that allows for use of `\textcitedelim`. The main advantage of that is that you can use `\iffinalcitedelim` to have the last item separated by 'and'.

```
\providebibmacro*{cite:reinit}{%
  \global\undef\cbx@lasthash
  \global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\providebibmacro*{cite:init}{\usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}

\newbibmacro*{citeauthor}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
    {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
        {}
        {\printnames{labelname}%
         \stepcounter{textcitecount}%
         \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
  \setunit{\textcitedelim}}   

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@citeauthor}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeauthor}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\providerobustcmd{\cbx@textcite@init}[2]{%
  \setcounter{textcitetotal}{0}%
  \setcounter{textcitecount}{0}%
  \def\cbx@savedcites{#1}#2\cbx@savedcites\empty}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}[\cbx@textcite@init\cbx@citeauthor]
  {\gdef\cbx@savedkeys{}%
   \citetrackerfalse%
   \pagetrackerfalse%
   \DeferNextCitekeyHook%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\ifthenelse{\iffirstcitekey\AND\value{multicitetotal}>0}
     {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{()(\thefield{multipostnote})}%
      \global\clearfield{multipostnote}}
     {}%
   \xappto\cbx@savedkeys{\thefield{entrykey},}%
   \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
     {}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}
  {}
  {\protected@xappto\cbx@savedcites{%
     [\thefield{prenote}][\thefield{postnote}]{\cbx@savedkeys}}}

\DeclareDelimcontextAlias{cbx@citeauthor}{textcite}
```

This should work for most styles as it `\provide`s commands with a sensible defaults that might not be available.

You might need

```
\renewcommand*{\iffinalcitedelim}{%
  \ifnumequal{\value{textcitecount}}{\value{textcitetotal}-1}}
```

though, but most standard `.cbx` styles have this as default.

Comment: I knew there was probably a quicker/better way....

Comment: This looks brilliant, though I really don't understand the last lot of code, which is probably what I want. Will have to experiment a little .... Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: @cfr The last bit is an adaption of `\textcite`. It implements a two-pass structure. Here `\citeauthor` is actually just a wrapper that counts how many different names there are. It then passes the citation list to `\cbx@citeauthor` which does the actual work. That way we make sure that we can actually count the number of different authors and insert an 'and' between the last two. The first solution can only b e used to reliably place the same delimiter between all names.

Comment: Thanks. I really don't know what I would do if you didn't answer my Biblatex questions!